# Paypal SDK Adaptive Payments Unknown cipher in list: TLSv1

Tags: php, ssl, curl, paypal

I'm trying to implement adaptive payments with SetPaymentOptions. I'm getting the following error:

SDK Exception
Type    PPConnectionException

Message     Unknown cipher in list: TLSv1

Detailed message    Error connecting to https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/SetPaymentOptions

I dont know what this means.  Any idea on how to get this working?  I have this for part of my code in the PPHttpconfig:

```
public static $DEFAULT_CURL_OPTS = array(
    CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 1,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,   // maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'PayPal-PHP-SDK',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array(),
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST => 'TLSv1',
);
```

Comment: Can you let us know what version of curl you are using ? You may be using a bit old version.

Comment: I did this: $version = curl_version();
echo $ssl_supported= $version['version'] ; got: 7.19.7

Comment: Can you pass entire $version ?

print_r($version);

Comment: Remove this line CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST => 'TLSv1' and then try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems if you are using NSS instead of OpenSSL, Having Cipher List is causing the issue, as TLSv1 is not in the NSS.

If you are having that error, you might want to run

```
php -r "print_r(curl_version());"
```

If the output has

```
[ssl_version] => NSS/...
```

It means, you have NSS. Then you can just remove the CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST from the array

```
public static $DEFAULT_CURL_OPTS = array(
    CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 1,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,   // maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'PayPal-PHP-SDK',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array(),
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 1,
);
```

EDIT: The release was made with the fix at : https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-php/releases/tag/v2.5.8

Comment: Thanks Jay. It actually goes to this screen now http://i.imgur.com/4uJ05lN.jpg . Is it suppose to do this?

Comment: Yes. Thats the result page for your request, and it is successful.

Comment: Jay doe you have a contact email? I have a few questions regarding this that im still confused on. thanks

Comment: You can reach me at japatel@paypal.com

Comment: @Jay Will there be a more permanent fix implemented? Also, is there a way to pass in this config as I'm using the composer/autoload solution and would rather not overwrite the whole class?

Comment: Hey @Zoop-Josh the Rest API SDK has a permanent fix that checks if the NSS is present, and would act accordingly. The fix is yet to be made on SDK Core. however, it should be released soon. I will update this thread as soon as I am done with the fix. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Jay. I will keep an eye out for the fix.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST => 'TLSv1',
> ```

There are not TLSv1 ciphers.
TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 use SSL 3.0 ciphers. TLS 1.2 adds some new ciphers but still supports the SSL 3.0 ciphers. If you want to make your code safe against POODLE you need to care about the SSL protocol version only, not the ciphers.