# Using paypal merchant sdk with curl enabled with NSS

Tags: php, curl, paypal, express-checkout

I am using [paypal merchant sdk](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php) and my curl version goes as

```
 [version_number] => 463623
[age] => 3
[features] => 1597
[ssl_version_number] => 0
[version] => 7.19.7
[host] => x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
[ssl_version] => NSS/3.14.0.0
[libz_version] => 1.2.3
[protocols] => Array
```

Because of NSS I am getting error `Unknown cipher in list: TLSv1`

Many posts suggest making changes to pphttpconfig.php file and remove option  CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST => 'TLSv1' , do I have any other option which can be used because since I am using composer chaces are there that library get updated and my changes gets overwritten.So how can I make sure that my integration works fine

Answer (score 0):

Possible Duplicate

[Paypal SDK Adaptive Payments Unknown cipher in list: TLSv1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882530/paypal-sdk-adaptive-payments-unknown-cipher-in-list-tlsv1/26892691?noredirect=1#comment44264463_26892691)

I have been working on [REST API SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK), which had a similar issue as you are facing. I was able to make the [change there](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConfig.php#L67), but I didnt get time to fix [this](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-php/blob/namespace-5.3/lib/PayPal/Core/PPHttpConfig.php). If you feel, you could send me a quick pull request, with pretty much the same fix as the REST one, and I would be more than happy to accept it.

Comment: created a pull request https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-php/pull/62 .Please have a review