# Can't process with PayPal using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, vue.js

After I install and configure, all what I need is to make a payment using `Paypal (Sandbox)`.

I copy/pasted the both `Keys` in my `.env` file.
Everything works great locally, but after I uploaded it to a shared hosting and process the same payment, I got the following error, and I don't know why. 
[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fzs1k.jpg)
Errors Lines =>

```
PayPalConnectionException {#311 ▼
  -url: "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"
  -data: null
  #message: "failed setting cipher list"
  #code: 59
  #file: "/home/artemal/www/artemal/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConnection.php"
  #line: 181
  trace: {▶}
}
```

Comment: Please check the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882530/paypal-sdk-adaptive-payments-unknown-cipher-in-list-tlsv1

Comment: Okey @Stephan-v i will Bro

Comment: I did Comment and remove this line : 
        CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST => 'TLSv1:TLSv1.2'

and i get another issue like  [ error picture  ][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9xL9.jpg

Comment: @Stephan-v Thanks by the way

Comment: So what SSL version are you actually using now? Please don't just change things without understanding the implications.

Comment: Okey sir i'm using laravel so when i did :     dd( curl_version() );
i got this :  [Picture] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzLdO.jpg)

Comment: what do you think sir